# my python socket wont receive?

Tags: python, sockets

I am having python socket issues
I can start the script, Use wireshark, The data is sent to my PC,
But Python doesn't see the data?
As I can see what the socket is supposed to be receiving on a packet sniffer, Any Ideas?
I have tried just about everything, and I can't seem to get it to work no matter what.
I have been wanting to get this done forever, but haven't had any more time to work on it.
But now I do.

```
import sys
import socket
import os
import hashlib
import subprocess

class ConnectToServer:

    port = 12345
    host = "80.69.129.118"

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 12345))

    s.connect((host , port))
    message = "LOGON\n Protocol-Version: 2.0\n App-type: Windows x86\n Operator: PC_CLIENT\n name: palpythonbot@gmail.com\n capabilities: 4\n"

class SendAndReceive:

    s.send(message)
    rply = s.recv(10)
    #####WONT RECEIVE RPLY
    print rply
    passmd5 = hashlib.md5()
    passmd5.update(pal_pass)
    authmessage = "AUTH\n Encryption-Type: 1\n Online-Status: 1\n Last: 1\n" +     passmd5.hexdigest()
    s.send(authmessage)
    rply1 = s.recv(10)
    print rply1
    s.close()
```

Comment: Post your code inline and not using an external service, please.

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to the smallest reproducible example that demonstrates your problem? I'd also suggest using some functions or classes - in it's current form it's horrible to read.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that look suspicious:

- You use bind() on a socket you lateron use for communication. This is typically only used on a socket that you use for accept() calls.
- Check if your peer wants CRLF line endings. If it's waiting for the CRLF pair, it won't recognize the multiple lines you sent as even a single complete line.

BTW, readability hack:

```
authmessage = ("AUTH\n"
               " Encryption-Type: 1\n"
               " Online-Status: 1\n")
```

The brackets extend the expression and "two" "strings" are automatically concatenated. Also, just as I write that, are the leading spaces correct?

Comment: the peer replies, python just doesnt notice it